# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' in Python code

Tags: python

I'm trying to translate a C program to Python but it gives one error. What have I done wrong?

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-

datos=open("bio.dat","r+")

h=[];numero=[];edad=[];peso=[]

nombre=[]
#Creando matriz para nombre
for i in range(100):
   nombre.append([0]*50)


apellido=[]
#Creando matriz para apellido
for i in range(100):
  apellido.append([0]*50)

 sexo=[]
 #Creando matriz para sexo
 for i in range(100):
   sexo.append([0]*50)


sumah=[];sumap=[];sumahp=[];sumah2=[]

for l in xrange(1,26):
 h+=[l]
 sumah+=h
 peso+=[l]
 sumap+=peso
 sumahp+=h*peso
 sumah2+=h*h

promh=sumah/25.0
promp=sumap/25.0

a=(sumah*sumap-25*sumahp)/(sumah2-25*sumah*sumah)
b=promp-a*promh
```

And this is the error I get:

```
 File "datobiometrico.py", line 34, in <module>
 sumahp+=h*peso
 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Comment: `h` is empty, and you are trying to access an element from it, when it has no such elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the list is empty:

```
h=[]
```

You'll have to add 25 elements to it before the code works (on a side note: lists' indexes start at `0`, not at `1` as seems implied in your code). Do this:

```
h.append(firstValue)
h.append(secondValue)
# and so on
```

In Python lists start without elements, with no values - they're *not* like arrays in other programming languages, that initially have a fixed length. Lists in Python start with a length of zero, so even `h[0]` will fail *unless* you add elements, for instance using `append()`.

**UPDATE**

So, you want to translate some C code to Python. Your approach is wrong, you're initializing *numbers* as if they were *lists*, and the way you're accessing elements is incorrect, too. This is how the C code would look like in Python:

```
sumah  = 0
sumap  = 0
sumahp = 0
sumah2 = 0

for i in xrange(1, 26):
    sumah  += h[i]
    sumap  += peso[i]
    sumahp += h[i]*peso[i]
    sumah2 += h[i]*h[i]
```

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita The code is incomplete, it won't compile. What is `h`? what is `peso`? you must post a code example that _runs_ when copied into the command line. Also, you should definitely NOT change the question after it has been answered, better post a new question

Comment: You dont have to compile in Python. But if it helps, i have already made a code in C that actually compiles. Posted

Comment: Python code _is_ compiled when you run it from the command line. What I mean is: don't post code that can't be run by other people, you must post all the code necessary so other people can run it

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita there you go. For what is worth: this is not the correct way to ask a question in Stack Overflow. You must not change the question along the way, and posting a picture with code, expecting people to translate it for you … that won't work, people won't help you.

Comment: I never asked people for translate all the code. Actually i only posted the code so they can see what im trying to do. Because like i said before 'But if it helps, i have already made a code in C that actually compiles'. The question is clear enough: 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' in Python code'. Not 'Can anyone translate this for me?'
Now, i already erased all the pictures and posted the code im doing, because like you said: 'don't post code that can't be run by other people, you must post all the code necessary so other people can run it'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60857/discussion-between-oscar-lopez-and-vanesa-piedrahita).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should do in Python, which nobody has mentioned yet, is to avoid using `+=` on lists. Use either `append()` or `extend()` instead. They work like this:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist.append(5)
# mylist is now [1,2,3,4,5]
otherlist = [6,7,8]
mylist.extend(otherlist)
# mylist is now [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The `append()` method takes one argument, and adds that argument to the end of the list. The `extend()` method takes one argument, *which should be a **sequence** such as another list*, and adds every item in that sequence to your original list, one at a time. What's the difference? Well, if you pass a list to the `append()` method, it will add just **one** entry to your list, and that list will be the other list. Observe:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4]
list_b = [1,2,3,4]

list_a.append([5,6,7])
# list_a is now [1,2,3,4,[5,6,7]]
print len(list_a) # This will be 5
print list_a[-1] # This will print the list [5,6,7]

list_b.extend([5,6,7]
# list_b is now [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print len(list_b) # This will be 7
print list_b[-1] # This will print the integer 7
```

Why do I mention this? Because right now you're using `+=` on lists, which has the same effect as the `extend()` method. So your code is doing things like `h+=[l]`, which has the same effect as `h.extend([l])`, adding a single item to the list. But it's much better to say `h.append(l)` instead, because that way it's a lot clearer what your code is intended to do.